# Use Apache CSVParser get number not in scientific notation

Tags: java

i have a csv file, and one column is set to scientific notation.
i get number in scientific notation(like 4.67E+5) by following code

```
step1  CSVFormat csvFormat = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withIgnoreHeaderCase(true);
step2  CSVParser csvParser = new CSVParser(fileReader, csvFormat);
step3  List<CSVRecord> csvRecords = csvParser.getRecords();
```

Is there any methods which can I use to transfer the scientific notations existing in csvRecords (in step3)     into the normal values with all digits visible (The type can be String, int, long......)    and the normal values are still stored in csvRecords (in step3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `CSVRecord` method `get()` which returns a `String` and convert the text yourself.

The method `Double.parseDouble(String)` should fit very well.

**UPDATE**

For example in your case

```
String n = "4.67E+5";
System.out.println(Double.parseDouble(n));
```

Returns

```
467000.0
```

Comment: Sorry to reply late. Do you mean after my step3, using **get()** to get a **String** and convert it to double? But after **CSVParser()**,the data in String is exactly the String '4.67E+5' which is not what I need like '467123'. I  wonder how to turn '4.67E+5' to '467123' before parsering. Thanks! :)

Comment: @Wilde Yes, `Double.parseDouble` is exactly what you need, if you use with `4.67E+5` the method will return `467123`. I have just updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.It's really a effective way.And some errors is caused by incorrect data in csv file.